# Colon(:) and number in filename in Visio

Tags: file, ms-office, visio

I have done some search but nothing same up really.

I have got a visio file, and when I double click and open it up, it open 5 copies of the document in same window and names them as format of filename:1, filename:2 and so on. they seem identical.

any idea Why  this happens?

thanks for the help.

Regards

Mesut

Comment: 5 different copies of the the same file? Or 1 file that contains 5 tabs with the same name?

Comment: one visio program and 5 window opened containing same file, but the name of the  windows are numbered as x.vsd:1

Comment: This is not a programming question. Voting to move to superuser.

Comment: I am happy to get it moved to superuser website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the windows are showing the same file. When this file was saved there were multiple windows open. This workspace is saved with the file. When you reopen the file the same views are opened. To stop this close all but one window and then save the file.